# format phone number to US mobile no format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eg: 1234567890  --> 123-456-7890

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple regex. Match 3 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits and insert hyphens.

```js
const input = '1234567890';
const formatted = input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, and hope it helps!

```
<input id="phoneField" onKeyUp="phoneNumberConverter()">

<script>
function phoneNumberConverter()
{
    var number = document.getElementById("phoneField").value;
  if (number.length == 10)
  {
    var number = number.substring(0, 3) + "-" + number.substring(3, 6) + "-" + number.substring(6, 10);
    document.getElementById("phoneField").value = number;
  }

}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cewvqgy9/11/